# How to fill DropDownList Dynamic

Tags: asp.net

I have some Asp.net dropdownList control,
List docs have 3 properties : DocID , UniqueIdentifier, Name.
How to fill DDL only with this record which goes across "IF" condition. It's a pseudo code.

```
 List<IR_DocumentType> docs = IR_DocumentType.getDocType();
 foreach (IR_DocumentType item in docs)
 {
    if (item.DocID ==1)
    {
    }
 }
 //dropdownList
 DDL.DataSoure = docs;
 DDL.Bind();
```

\

Answer (score 0):

See code below

```
List<IR_DocumentType> docs = IR_DocumentType.getDocType();
 DDL.DataSoure = new DataTable(); // you can skip this 
 DDL.DataTextField = "Name";  //or "UniqueIdentifier"
 DDL.DataValueField = "DocID" ;
 DDL.Bind();
 foreach (IR_DocumentType item in docs)
  {
 if (item.DocID ==1)
    {
     DDL.Items.Insert(item.DocID, item.Naem );
     //or item.UniqueIdentifier you can also use     
    //a counter instead of item.DocID
                }
            }
```

let me know it this helps

Answer (score 0):

```
        List<IR_DocumentType> docs = IR_DocumentType.getDocType();

        foreach (IR_DocumentType item in docs)
        {
            if (item.DocID ==1) // your condition
            {
              DDL.Items.Add(new ListItem(item.Name, item.UniqueIdentifier);
            }
        }
```